# Не получается указать путь к файлу

Tags: java, javafx

Когда разрабатывал JavaFX приложение, столкнулся с данной проблемой. Все мои файлы **.java** находились в папке **sample**. Я решил разместить классы-контроллеры и прочие классы в разных папках, вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`getClass().getResource("../assets/login.fxml")` возвращает `null`. Что я указал неправильно? Насколько я понимаю, нужно относительно Main файла подняться на директорию вверх, а дальше уже `assets/login.fxml`, тогда почему `../assets/login.fxml` не работает?
Как только я возвращаю все файлы в папку sample, все файлы нормально подгружаются

```
package sample.classes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("../assets/login.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Vote app");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Не помогает даже такой вариант, где я в упор говорю, откуда брать fxml файл.

```
URL url = new URL("C:\\Users\\nklns\\IdeaProjects\\Java_CourseWork\\src\\sample\\assets\\login.fxml");
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

нажимаешь правую мышки на файле[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выбираешь нужный путь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вообще надо быть повнимательней, у тебя искомый файл лежит в папке assets/pictures а ты ищешь его в  assets/

Comment: Нет, файл login.fxml лежит в sample/assets/login.fxml. Всё работает нормально, когда все классы лежат в sample, файл выгружается по пути assets/login.fxml